# How convert loaded Image in browser to base64 string?

Tags: javascript, qt, webview, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I loaded a url in qml `WebView`, In this page there is an image and is displaying with `WebView` but when I get the source of the page with `document.documentElement.innerHTML',I see the image tag like this:

```
<td class="labelColumn">
<img class="g-Image" title="Captha Image" src="https://website.com/user-account/gwt/entrypoint/registeruser.captcha" style="height: 35px; width: 130px;">
</td>
```

But the `WebView` is displaying this image and I my question is that I should be able to get the image in base64 string or the path of it. How can I find the image?

When  I run `document.images[0].src` I will get `https://website.com/user-account/gwt/entrypoint/registeruser.captcha`.

I want the content of the image ,It may be base64 string or the path or... .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert an image into Base64 string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HTMl5 `<canvas>` element.

Load the image inside of the canvas and then use the [`toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement) method/function. That should give you the base64 output.